# Why and what of curl and then sudo apt-get?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, apt-get

To install node on Linux, per the docs, I had to do:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I get the second statement, but not the first.

`curl` will download the contents, right? Then pipe it to a a new command? Which does what? I know the -E preserves environment variables, but what does `bash -` do?

And why do I need to do that, before doing `apt-get`? Shouldn't `apt-get` get me the latest version? Or is this always the way to do it with `apt-get`?

Comment: `apt install nodejs` is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`curl` is downloading a bash script and piping its contents to a new bash shell running as root with your current account's environment variables.

`-` is telling bash to read from stdin, which in this case is the output from curl - the contents of the bash script.

The script is actually adding its own repositories for `nodejs` to your package manager which is why you install it after running the script. Using the official Node repositories ensures you install the latest version.

You can [take a look](https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x) at the bash script.

The "one liner" you have is an alternative to first downloading the script to file and then running it with `sudo`:

```
wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x
sudo -E bash ./setup_4.x
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line download and execute an installation of the repositories of **[NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)**. It is a platform to deploy,and control node.js applications.

The second line is **node.js**.